# Mongo DB insert function syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I am a but confused on the purpose of the optional callback seen within Mongo's insert function. What exactly is this used for?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo'; // learnyoumongo is the Database

var firstName = process.argv[2];
var lastName = process.argv[3];

var doc = {
  'firstName': firstName,
  'lastName': lastName
}

 mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
 if (err) throw err;

 // db gives access to the database
 var docs = db.collection('docs');
 docs.insert(doc,function(err, data){ // What is the purpose of this callback function?
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
   db.close()
 })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.insert` is an asynchronous call. It will return immediately, before the operation has completed.

If you want to do something after the insert has actually been done (including checking if it succeeded), you need to do that in the callback (which is invoked afterwards).

Note that you are doing the same thing with `mongo.connect`: You can only start using the connection from within the callback.

This is a very common pattern in Javascript programming: Fire off a background operation, receive the result some time later as arguments to a callback.